# Angular Azure AD Token Request Pattern for Single Page Application with Backend for Token Management

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, pkce

I am trying to set up Angular app Single Sign On using Auzre AD authentication. After onboarding I got below parameter and values

- Client ID
- Client Secret
- Tenant ID,
- OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint
  (v2):https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/authorize,
- OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (v2):
  https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token,
  OpenID Connect metadata document:
- https://login.microsoftonline.com//v2.0/.well-known/openid
  configuration,

How to use this value for different API calls. I am looking for guidance on API sequence call required for SSO.

I don't want to store token on client side so planning to handle it through backend.

I already created a service which will return session object with help of fingerprint. What will be my next API call to  fetch the auth code url and then token.

Comment: Do you want to use APIM to fetch the auth code url and then token?

Comment: not using APIM here

Answer (score 0):

> What will be my next API call to fetch the auth code url and then token.

To fetch the **auth code** make use of below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
&code_challenge=***
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

[image]

Generated the **access token** via Postman using below parameters:

*For sample, I generated access token for Microsoft Graph API*

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code_verifier:S256
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

Using the above generated token, you can call Microsoft Graph API:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

You can call any APIs by granting the API permissions to the Microsoft Entra ID application and changing the scope parameter.

***To implement the same in Angular SSO, refer below:***

[microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/lib/msal-angular at dev · AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js · GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular) by konstantin-msft

[Tutorial: Create an Angular app that uses the Microsoft identity platform for authentication using auth code flow - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code)